# Rewrite url to site.php as site

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is my files

```
index.php
blog.php
about.php
```

I am accessing it as

```
localhost/index.php or localhost
localhost/blog.php
localhost/about.php
```

How can i rewrite .htaccess so that i can access it by

```
localhost/
localhost/blog
localhost/about
```

**Update**

My image are not displaying once i applied the below provided .htaccess, can any give fix this ?

Comment: Do you have an example of your .htaccess configuration attempts so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
Options -MultiViews # optional Depends on Server
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

**EDIT:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: It works but image are not appearing :( It has the common path `img` but once i access my image url become `booking/a.png` how can i update in the .htaccess to refere to img folder for .png and.jpg format images like you have done to .php ?

Comment: include this in your page `<base href="htt://yourdomain.com" />`

Comment: you can also try my second option. please check my answer after EDIT

Comment: it should work fine. change `yourdomain.com` to your `sub.domain.com`

Comment: it is not working in the sub domain, that's the prob :

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71422/discussion-between-lea-tano-and-user4584846).

Comment: I opened a chat...please join so we can fix the issue without extending comments

Answer (score 0):

**Simple try this in `.htaccess` file :**

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1.html
```

Comment: Mine  is `.php` files

Comment: @user4584846, replace it with `.php` instead of `.html`

Comment: I replaced, it works  but images are not loading, is it possible to exclude for images ?

Comment: @user4584846, change your relative URIs in your resources.use `absolute paths` of the images,css..

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```